# How do you create a css transition fade on a sprite image?

Tags: html, css

I am using sprite image links for some of my menu items , positioning with background-position. I would like to make a fade effect in and out of the hover. I set up a

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/6q2hH/

```
<li class="mobileimg"><a href="#" class="mobileimage" title="Go Mobile"></a></li>

    li.mobileimg .mobileimage{
     display:block;
     background:transparent url('http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Templates/DA-2011/DA-2013/Nike_13/img/mobile.png')no-repeat;
     width: 30px;
     height:30px;
     margin-top:9px;
     margin-left:3px;
    }

    li.mobileimg .mobileimage:hover {background-position:0px -29px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the opacity of `.mobileimage:hover` to something less than 1. For cross-browser compatibility, try:

```
.mobileimage:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -khtml-opacity: .5;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)";
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Then, to create an actual transition effect, you need to tell `.mobileimage` to create a transition on opacity instead of just switching to `opacity: .5` immediately:

```
.mobileimage {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease;/* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease;   /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease;    /* IE10? */
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease;     /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;     
}
```

`500ms` is how long it takes for the opacity to change, and `ease` is the type of transition effect. See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q2hH/8/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6q2hH/3/

```
li.mobileimg .mobileimage{
 display:block;
 background:transparent url('http://www.dagrafixdesigns.com/Templates/DA-2011/DA-2013/Nike_13/img/mobile.png')no-repeat;
 width: 30px;
 height:30px;
 margin-top:9px;
 margin-left:3px;
}

li.mobileimg .mobileimage:hover {
    background-position:0px -29px;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadingItOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadingItOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
}
```

You can tweak the behavior based on your needs. Check [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) for more info.

Also remember that this is only a WebKit example for Safari/Chrome/Chromium/etc. Other prefixes are (all animation tags need a prefix, this is only one example);

```
animation-name // Vanilla (general CSS)
-moz-animation-name // Firefox
-o-animation-name // Opera
-ms-animation-name // Internet Explorer
```

And for the frames;

```
@keyframes fadingItOut {
@-moz-keyframes fadingItOut {
@-o-keyframes fadingItOut {
@-ms-keyframes fadingItOut {
```

Comment: just checked out your demo, i don't see any fading or transition in IE,FF or Chrome , just the same as before, hover over image and pop the background position changes

Comment: Check the full answer, add the extra prefixes and it will work.